# Trick of summing reciprocals or what are they doing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given x,y,z are distinct positive real numbers

qty A:

$$\frac{x^2(y+z) + y^2(x+z) +z^2(x+y)}{xyz}$$

qty B:

$$6$$

Quantity A is greater
Quantity B is greater
Both the quantities are equal

I can get qty A rewritten to

$$(\frac{x}{z} + \frac{z}{x}) + (\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}) + (\frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{y})$$

However from here, other than plugging in semi-arbitrary values for $x,y,z$ I'm not sure how to compare that to 6.

Comment: Look at the function $t \mapsto t + \frac{1}{t}$.

Answer (score 0):

use that for $$x>0$$ and $$y>0$$ we get $$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\geq 2$$

Comment: Other than guessing and checking multiple values of x and y is there an intuitive way to get that to be more obvious?  I haven't been in school for about a decade so I'm rather rusty.

Comment: this can easily proved by the $AM-GM$ inequality

Comment: @DeanMacGregor $$t + \frac{1}{t} = 2 + \biggl( t - 2 + \frac{1}{t}\biggr) = 2 + \frac{1}{t}(t^2 - 2t + 1) = 2 + \frac{(t-1)^2}{t}$$